# Removing an h1 tag from a Magento template

Tags: magento

I have replaced the header tags on my website with pictures but the template is still displaying the header text in an h1 tag. Where would I need to go to remove this tag from all the web pages? Thanks!

Comment: Did you clear cache (if any)? Are you sure you remove it from the right template (try turning on template hints in the admin)

Comment: Great! that template hint thing will come in handy in the future. Make it an answer so i can give ya credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing cache (if any)

You may not be removing it from the right template  so try turning on template hints in the admin

See [How do I turn on template path hints](https://support.sweettoothrewards.com/entries/21255937-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your admin, then `System -> Configuration`.

On the left hand column, go to `Advanced -> Developer`

Now select the store view that you are working on, on the top left.

Under `Debug`, turn `Template Path Hints` on.

Now refresh the site to see exactly what file you need to edit.